# Function call and definition have different names in stack trace

Tags: javascript, devtools

I was trying to understand the JavaScript on a website when I found a weird phenomenon. I enabled breakpoints for XHRs in devtools and was reading through the stack trace when it hit the breakpoint. The issue is this.

There would be a function definition that is something like:

```js
function foo(someObject) {
  //Some code
}
```

and when I went one more step up the stack trace to see the call to this function, I'd see something like:

```js
bar(someobject);
```

The name of the call doesn't match the definition! Someone please explain how this works. Some references to articles would be appreciated too.
This may be a rookie question so thank you for the patience.

**Edit 1 - Here are some screenshots:**

[image]

This is at the last item in the stack. The code paused at line 1829. This is inside the function named `_()` starting at line 1805. If I jump one step back in the stack trace,

[image]

it jumps to line 268 of the same js file, where the function call is. But the call is to `t.scheduleFn()`, not to `_()`. I have checked and verified that the object passed in is identical to the object received at the definition. Please drop a comment if you need any more info.

If you need to see this live, please go to [this website](https://selfregistration.cowin.gov.in/), turn on breakpoints for XHRs, enter any number into the input field, click on 'Get OTP' and look at the stack trace.

**Edit 3 - Here's some of the code:**

Please read the comments that I've added.
This is the function inside which the code paused:

```js
function _(e) { //Note that this is the function name
            const o = e.data,
            c = o.target;
            c[i] = !1,
            c[h] = !1;
            const l = c[r];
            d || (d = c[s], g = c[a]),
            l && g.call(c, 'readystatechange', l);
            const u = c[r] = () =>{
              if (c.readyState === c.DONE) if (!o.aborted && c[i] && 'scheduled' === e.state) {
                const n = c[t.__symbol__('loadfalse')];
                if (n && n.length > 0) {
                  const r = e.invoke;
                  e.invoke = function () {
                    const n = c[t.__symbol__('loadfalse')];
                    for (let t = 0; t < n.length; t++) n[t] === e && n.splice(t, 1);
                    o.aborted || 'scheduled' !== e.state || r.call(e)
                  },
                  n.push(e)
                } else e.invoke()
              } else o.aborted || !1 !== c[i] || (c[h] = !0)
            };
            return d.call(c, 'readystatechange', u),
            c[n] || (c[n] = e),
            T.apply(c, o.args), //The code paused here.
            c[i] = !0,
            e
          }
```

If I went one step back to see the call to the function `_()` I see this:

```
scheduleTask(e, t) {
            let n = t;
            if (this._scheduleTaskZS) this._hasTaskZS && n._zoneDelegates.push(this._hasTaskDlgtOwner),
            n = this._scheduleTaskZS.onScheduleTask(this._scheduleTaskDlgt, this._scheduleTaskCurrZone, e, t),
            n || (n = t);
             else if (t.scheduleFn) t.scheduleFn(t); //The debugger shows that this is where the call to _() happened.
             else {
              if (t.type != S) throw new Error('Task is missing scheduleFn.');
              k(t)
            }
            return n
          }
```

My question is simply, how can a call to `t.scheduleFn()` go to `_()`. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Please post require part of code, it’s not enough to understand.

Comment: Screenshots don't count, post the relevant code as text here

Comment: @cloned in the case of him showing the results in devtools, I would expect him to post a screenshot. But, however, yes - he should post the *code* as text.

Comment: @edddd a good example of why you shouldn't post a website and say *go to it* - it returns a 403 error for me...

Make sure you post relevant code to your question so that we can have immediate access to it, instead of relying on third party sources - even if it is the motive behind the question.

Comment: @Reality I've made an edit, do let me know if it's enough.

Comment: @eddd I am not educated in using devtools enough to know - I am merely helping you to provide better resources for those who do...

Comment: I don't know how a call to t.scheduleFn() go to _(), but basically, this called  Name mangling, where the compiler changes the names of identifiers you can read more from this wiki and google it to better understand

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling